# Week over week change of status using SQL

Tags: sql

I am trying to write a SQL which will give me the count of users who's status changed over the period of week over week.

For e.g. User_id 1 has a status of 1 on `week_end_dt` of '2020-01-04' and then the status changed to 0 for the next `week_end_dt`.
So for the first week all the 4 user's had status 1, hence the count would be 4. For the next week, except for user 3 rest changed their status, hence the count would be 1. So on and so forth.

**Output**

```
week_end_dt  count_changed_0_1    count_change_1_0
2020-01-04        4                        0
2020-01-11        1                        0
2020-01-18        1                        1
```

The last row (above) is because user 2 changed from 0 to 1 while user 3 changed from 1 to 0.

```
create table user_status (user_id int, week_end_dt date, status int);

insert into user_status values (1,'2020-01-04', 1);
insert into user_status values (1,'2020-01-11', 0);
insert into user_status values (1,'2020-01-18', 0);
insert into user_status values (1,'2020-01-25', 0);
insert into user_status values (1,'2020-02-01', 0);

insert into user_status values (2,'2020-01-04', 1);
insert into user_status values (2,'2020-01-11', 0);
insert into user_status values (2,'2020-01-18', 1);
insert into user_status values (2,'2020-01-25', 0);
insert into user_status values (2,'2020-02-01', 0);

insert into user_status values (3,'2020-01-04', 1);
insert into user_status values (3,'2020-01-11', 1);
insert into user_status values (3,'2020-01-18', 0);
insert into user_status values (3,'2020-01-25', 1);
insert into user_status values (3,'2020-02-01', 0);
insert into user_status values (3,'2020-02-08', 1);
insert into user_status values (3,'2020-02-15', 0);
insert into user_status values (3,'2020-02-22', 1);

insert into user_status values (4,'2020-01-04', 1);
insert into user_status values (4,'2020-01-11', 0);
insert into user_status values (4,'2020-01-18', 0);
insert into user_status values (4,'2020-01-25', 0);
insert into user_status values (4,'2020-02-01', 1);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have data for every week (no gaps) as in your sample data, you can use `lag()` and aggregation like this:

```
select week_end_dt,
       sum(case when prev_status = status then 0 else 1 end) as num_changes
from (select us.*, lag(status) over (partition by user_id order by week_end_dt) as prev_status
      from user_status us
     ) us
group by week_end_dt
order by week_end_dt;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=c0dd8881d2bc3a2fe8fd88f57509be8f) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: This query is giving just the change of status correct ? either 0 to 1 or 1 to 0 ?

Comment: @Ravi . . . Any change.  If the previous status is not the same as the status in a given week.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Just one modification that I am trying to do is find out those records whose status did not change over the entire period of time. Lag/ Lead simply looks for previous value and not the entire set.

Comment: @Ravi . . .For that, you can use `min()` and `max()` or `count(distinct)`.  You can ask a new question.  Be sure to include an appropriate database tag.